# rotate spinner arrow android

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, dropdown

i am trying to rotate spinner arrow when spinner click. i try different  solution but not get exact result.
i want that rotate arrow from up to down when it select.

this is my xml code for spinner.

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_border">
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/pricespinner"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="30dp"
                        android:popupBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:entries="@array/pricearray"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/spnrimg"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_down_arrow" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```

this is in activity.

```
ss=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.pricespinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pricearray));
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        ss.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```